# different theme in one website

Tags: themes, database

Assume this is my site name : `www.example.com.`

I saw different websites have different themes in a site. For example I want to have different themes for `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/othertheme.` I know it should have different database for that. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the best use cases for [WordPress Multisite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite). There are some plugins ([like this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-theme/)) that do this on a per-page or per-category basis, but I've never used them.

Multisite has a lot of nice advantages (network-wide updates, user management, etc), along with some fun extra bugs (a lot of the recent core security updates have been for multisite-specific issues) and plugins that don't work on multisite.

I would recommend reading ["Don't Use WordPress Multisite"](http://halfelf.org/2011/dont-use-wordpress-multisite/) from .org support guru @ipstenu first, but it sounds like your use case is a good one for multisite.